# When is $\phi(a^n+b^n+c^n)=0\mod n$?

Tags: reference-request, diophantine-equations, congruences, arithmetic-functions

A corollary [Zsigmondy's Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZsigmondyTheorem.html) leads to the [following congruence](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientFunction.html) (one can look to $(24)$),$\phi(a^n+b^n)=0\mod n$ whenever $a, b$ are coprime and $n \neq 2$ and $(a,b)\neq(1,1)$. (Here  $\phi$ is the Euler totient function.) Is there any characterization of when $\phi(a^n+b^n+c^n)=0\bmod n$ assuming that $a,b,c$ are coprime integers?

Comment: I have no idea how your initial claim follows from Zsigmondy's Theorem (could you explain?). It is nevertheless true for $(a,b)\neq(1,1)$ though, as we can easily see $ab^{-1}$ has order $2n$ modulo $a^n+b^n$ (as the least $k$ for which $(ab^{-1})^k\equiv\pm 1$ is $n$ for size reasons). This argument sadly doesn't generalize to three numbers.

Comment: you may check [this](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientFunction.html) and see (24)

Comment: @Wojowu, Have you checked (24) in mathworld for looking how the titled claims follows ? I have linked it in the question